# Efficiently update a stock order book (maybe using numpy)

Tags: python, numpy, optimization

I'm following instructions [here](https://github.com/binance/binance-spot-api-docs/blob/master/web-socket-streams.md#how-to-manage-a-local-order-book-correctly).

Effectively the problem boils down to this:

```
# P is the previous orderbook state (in reality there's bids and asks, let's pick one: bids)
# Q is the update
# can assume P and Q are ordered

P = [           [1, 10], [2, 20],          [5, 50] ]
Q = [ [0, 100], [1, 11], [2,  0], [3, 30]          ]

# - if (x,y1) in P and (x,y2) in Q, export (x,y2) (new value)
# - if (x,y) in P and (x,0) in Q, don't export (it's cancelled)

# Want this:
R = [ [0, 100], [1, 11],          [3, 30], [5, 50] ]
```

The following algorithm accomplishes this:

```py
def merge(P, Q, verbose=False):
    i, j = 0, 0

    pr = print if verbose else lambda *x: None
    
    R = []

    while i < len(P) and j < len(Q):
        pr('Comparing', P[i], Q[j])

        if P[i][0] < Q[j][0]:
            pr('  add item', P[i])
            R.append(P[i])
            i += 1

        elif Q[j][0] < P[i][0]:
            pr('  add item', Q[j])
            R.append(Q[j])
            j += 1

        elif P[i][0] == Q[j][0]:
            if Q[j][1] == 0:
                pr('  delete item', P[i])
            else:
                pr('  replace item', P[i], 'with', Q[j])
                R.append(Q[j])

            i += 1
            j += 1

    R.extend(P[i:])
    R.extend(Q[j:])

    pr('Done')

    pr(R)

P = [           [1, 10], [2, 20],         [5, 0], [6, 60] ]
Q = [ [0, 100], [1, 11], [2,  0], [3, 30]                 ]

merge(P, Q, verbose=True)
```

However I have a feeling it is inefficient.

Time profiling with dummy data:

```
import numpy as np
from time import time

r = lambda N: np.random.random((N, 2))

PQ = r(1000)  # common to P and Q, so volume changed for these prices
PQ[:100] = 0  # deleted by Q
P = np.concatenate([PQ, r(100)])  # some pricepoints in P didn't change volume to Q
Q = np.concatenate([PQ, r(100)])  # some fresh pricepoints arrive in Q

# both will be sorted in reality
P = P[np.argsort(P[:,0])]
Q = P[np.argsort(Q[:,0])]

t0 = time()
for i in range(100):
    merge(P, Q)
t1 = time()
print(t1 - t0)
```

... gives ~0.3s on my 2018 MacBookPro

Something tells me a 10x improvement is possible. But how to accomplish? Can I leverage the Power of numpy?

One thought I had is to add a column that is 0 for P and 1 for Q. e.g.

```
    P = np.c_[np.zeros(len(P)), P]
    Q = np.c_[np.ones(len(Q)), Q]
```

Another is that maybe I can use an OrderedDict.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python loops are generally slow. Numpy can barely help ere because the code is mostly sequential and the merge is not a generic one.
You can do that with **Numba** and by replacing the slow list appends by direct assignments of a temporary pre-allocated array:

```py
import numba as nb

@nb.njit('float64[:,::1](float64[:,::1],float64[:,::1])')
def merge(P, Q):
    i, j, k = 0, 0, 0
    assert P.shape[1] == Q.shape[1]
    R = np.empty((P.shape[0]+Q.shape[0], P.shape[1]), dtype=P.dtype)

    while i < len(P) and j < len(Q):
        if P[i,0] < Q[j,0]:
            R[k] = P[i]
            i += 1
            k += 1
        elif Q[j,0] < P[i,0]:
            R[k] = Q[j]
            j += 1
            k += 1
        elif P[i,0] == Q[j,0]:
            if Q[j][1] != 0:
                R[k] = Q[j]
                k += 1
            i += 1
            j += 1

    R = np.concatenate((R[:k], P[i:], Q[j:]))
    return R
```

I removed the debugging printing function call for sake of clarity and performance. The result is returned as a Numpy array. If you want a debugging function, its prototype should be well defined to be used in a Numba function (note that still `print` should work). This prototype is **230 times faster** than the original code on my machine.

Comment: That is insane! Might you consider providing a brief explanation of how Numba is achieving this performance gain (and what that `@nb.njit` line is accomplishing)?

Comment: Yeah, Python codes are usually executed using the CPython interpreter. Interpreter are slow. Numba compile the code at runtime  (thanks to `@nb.njit`) to run the code natively. However, the downside is that Numba require static types and only support a small subset of Python. Besides this direct assignments are much faster than `append` since the second cause the array to be resized (which is slow because of dynamic allocations). For more information about Numba, you can take a look to [the documentation examples](https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/dev/user/examples.html).

Comment: Is this performance comparable with a C++ implementation?

Comment: Probably not as fast, but it should be close to a naive C++ implementation I guess.